# Opposite of ng-cloak for loading message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know if this exists in the AngularJS framework, but essentially I'm looking for the opposite of ng-cloak, which hides elements until the page is compiled.  I was looking for a way to show a full screen loading message until the page is compiled.  Is there something built into the language to handle this?

Comment: Not that I know of, you can check out http://jh3y.github.io/progre-c-ss/ alternatively.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have resolved this using a somewhat hacky method as follows.  The following HTML is added at the end of the main page.

```
<div ng-show="::false" style="position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #353535; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 10000;">
    <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 26px; color: #CCC;">
        Loading
    </div>
</div>
```

The message is shown across the entire browser until the page is compiled, at which point ng-show takes over and hides the loading message.

**EDIT:**
Angular 1.3+ lets you use the `::` expression to prevent evaluating the expression in every digest cycle.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Comment: I think you can remove your simple quotes and simply set: `ng-show="false"`. Btw, this isn't so hacky to me.

Comment: It was hackier at first, I had ng-show"ScopeVariableThatDoesntExist", then I changed it to ng-show="'false'" which as you said, is less hacky.  Wouldn't removing the single-quotes make it evaluate to a scope variable? (e.g. $scope.false)

Comment: @helios456 no. But with single quotes it will evaluate to a string.

Comment: This answer is perfect, because it shows an understanding of how Angular really works. "ng-cloak" says "apply css styling (which loads quickly) until Angular has a chance to hit the control and remove the styling, which shows the control". Your method says "show some stuff on the screen until Angular has a chance to hit the control and hide it"

Comment: FYI the `::variable` syntax is more commonly known as one time binding

Comment: If you have a full screen loading image and you want to remove it from the page completely, just use `ng-if="false"` instead.

Answer (score 22):

```
<div ng-show>Loading Results...</div>
```

`ng-show` with no attribute specified compiles to `false`

Comment: Very intesresting answer.  For the sake of readability, I still prefer explicitely specifying the ="'false'", but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I like ng-show="::false". It's more readable (why would you put ng-show for something you wanted to hide?) and it also includes a one-time binding, which seems more efficient.

Comment: `ng-if` makes more sense than `ng-show` -- no benefit in leaving it within the DOM

Answer (score 6):

You can use css to archive this behavior.

Create a class:

```
.splash {
  display: none;
}

[ng-cloak].splash {
  display: block !important;
}
```

And then add:

```
<div class="splash" ng-cloak> Loading... </div>
```

This will show before the Angular code loads, and will hide after the angular code completes. Don't forget to wrap your angular code with ng-cloak too.

```
<div ng-cloak> Your code... </div>
```

Comment: I find this the simplest solution, that should be marked as the answer. no worries about digests or binding, pure css. Angular already has ng-cloak, OP is asking for the exact opposite, this answer is very simply the response that OP was asking for

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

> https://codepen.io/garethdweaver/pen/PqKLyB

It can be used without &:after, but the idea is well shown here, and my decision based on this was as follows:

```
  .cloak-loader
    display: none !important

  [ng-cloak].cloak-loader
    position: relative
    display: block !important
    .loader
      height: 50px
      display: flex
      justify-content: center
      align-items: center
```