# Too much delay to load data into DOM after successful response of service in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to load very large set of data into html table

1. Click on button.

   ```
   <a ng-click="get_product()">load data</a>
   ```
2. button call a function get_product

   ```
   $scope.get_product = function () {
     // loader image shown
     var get_product = PAYMENTCOLL.getStatusBasedPaymentCollection(); //service call
     get_product.success(function (data)
     {
       $scope.pagedItems = data; //set data into array
     });
     //loader image hide
   };
   ```
3. load `pagedItems` array into html table using `ng-repeat`.

**Case 1:**

In case of small set of data  the "loader image hide" when data completely has been loaded into DOM.

**Case 2:**

In case of Large set of data "loader image hide" but the data is still loading into DOM (it will take 3-4 seconds more to load data after hide loader).

**Purpose:**

My purpose is to show loader image until all data is successfully loaded into DOM. After loading all data into DOM I want to hide loader image.

**How can I resolve case 2 Issue ? Thanks Ahead**

Comment: This isn't very clear... What is the issue you have at the moment? "In case of Large set of data loader image hide but..." makes little sense to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but try one of these two: 1. try triggering that function from inside the part that takes a long time to render in your view (using `ng-init` or something). 2. run a `$timeout` without any time. this will trigger showing the table only on the next digest cycle.

Comment: My purpose is to show loader image until all data is successfully loaded into DOM. After loading all data into DOM I want to hide loader image.

Comment: and what I wrote in my comment didn't work? I'm pretty sure the $timeout solution at least should work

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052384/opposite-of-ng-cloak-for-loading-message

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using promises?

Use [$q promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) so that you can set `$scope.showLoaderImage` once the promise has been fulfilled.

```
$scope.get_product = function () {
    $scope.showLoaderImage = true;
    PAYMENTCOLL.getStatusBasedPaymentCollection().then(function (e) {
        $scope.showLoaderImage = false;
        $scope.pagesItems = e.data.d;
    }, function (err) {
        //Handle Errors
    })
};
```

In order to reflect the state of `$scope.showLoaderImage` in your DOM, use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), as below:

```
<div ng-show="showLoaderImage">
   <!-- Image here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I have update my question kindly check. In your solution I am not able to resolve my issue.